# how to programmatically delete uncommitted blocks in azure storage using blob service?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

We get an error 'The specified blob or block content is invalid' if we try to upload a block that is already present in server. how to clear those uncommittedblocks before user retries to upload the same blob?

```
code:'InvalidBlobOrBlock'
message:'The specified blob or block content is invalid.\nRequestId:1b015a55-201e-00be-7b1c-7e8fb8000000\nTime:2021-07-21T10:35:48.0075829Z'
name:'StorageError'
requestId:'1b015a55-201e-00be-7b1c-7e8fb8000000'
stack:'StorageError: The specified blob or block content is invalid
statusCode:400
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to clear those uncommittedblocks before user retries to upload the
> same blob?

AFAIK, there's no direct way to delete uncommitted blocks. Simplest way for you would be to create a blob with the same name and then delete that blob. When creating a blob with the same name, please ensure that it is uploaded without splitting the contents into blocks.

I wrote a blog post about this error some time back that you may find useful: https://gauravmantri.com/2013/05/18/windows-azure-blob-storage-dealing-with-the-specified-blob-or-block-content-is-invalid-error/.